# Bifurcated limit cycles from real eigenvalues

Tags: bifurcation

I have never heard of limit cycles bifurcated from real eigenvalues crossing zero. For the below system I believe that is the case. Is this bifurcation known and has a specific name?

For $d = b + i c \in \mathbb{C}$, $z(t) = x(t) + i y(t) \in \mathbb{C}$ and $a\in \mathbb{R}$, consider
\begin{equation}\label{rb1}
  \dot{z} = a z + d z \vert z \vert^2
\end{equation}
which can be written as
\begin{equation}
  \begin{aligned}
    & \dot{x} = a x + (b x - c y) (x^2 + y^2)\\
    & \dot{y} = a y + (b y + c x) (x^2 + y^2)
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
or in polar coordinates $z = r e^{i \theta}$,
\begin{aligned}
    & \dot{r} = a r + b r^3 \\
    & \dot{\theta} =  c r^2
  \end{aligned}
For $a < 0$ the solution $z=0$ is stable. For $a > 0$ it is unstable. So there is a bifurcation at $a = 0$.
If $c \ne 0$ and $a b < 0$ then there is a limit cycle $r^2 = - a/b$ which is stable if $b<0$ and unstable otherwise. The limit cycle is given by
$$
  z(t) = \sqrt{\frac{-a}{b}} e^{- i \frac{a c}{b} t }
$$
Also the period of the limit cycle goes to infinity as $a \downarrow 0$. So unlike the Hopf bifurcation case, this limit cycle is very slowly rotating.